# Removing list object given field value python

Tags: python-2.7, object, del

Given

This is not simply removing elements from a list; its removing but by using field value

```
philani = Student(20, "Philani Sithole", "Male", [64,65])
sarah = Student(19, "Sarah Jones", "Female", [82,58])
fabian = Student(50, "Fabian Hamza", "Male", [50,52])


students = [philani, sarah, fabian]
```

How can I remove the object fabian from students list given the name "Fabian Hamza"

Desired results:

```
students = [philani, sarah]
```

It tried this

```
name = "Fabian Hamza"
for i in xrange(len(students)):
    if hasattr(students[i], name):
        students.pop(i)
```

But its not working

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Removing elements from a List in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27443627/removing-elements-from-a-list-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension to achieve that:

```
[s for s in students if s.name != 'Fabian Hamza']
```

If you want just the list of names, try:

```
[s.name for s in students if s.name != 'Fabian Hamza']
```

Comment: I have tried but still it did not work - I am kind of new, can u try to elaborate more please...?

Comment: You can do the same with a simple for loop but list comprehension is a very interesting feature that you should take a look at.